Lost Parent Span for HTTP Client Spans
I've recently set up tracing in my application to monitor and debug the flow of requests. Everything seemed to be working fine, but I've encountered a peculiar issue with my HTTP client.
The issue: When there is an error in the HTTP request, the tracing works as expected, and I can see the parent span properly linked to the HTTP client spans. However, when the HTTP request completes successfully (without any errors), I lose the parent span of the HTTP client spans but still get them unattached with warning invalid parent span IDs.
this is the the httpClient I'm using:
    transport := traceHttp.NewTracedTransport(nil, otel.GetTracerProvider())
    httpClient:= http.Client{Transport: transport}

and the library:
package http

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptrace"

    "go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/httptrace/otelhttptrace"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace"
)

func NewTracedTransport(transport http.RoundTripper, provider trace.TracerProvider) *otelhttp.Transport {
    if transport == nil {
        transport = http.DefaultTransport
    }
    return otelhttp.NewTransport(
        transport,
        otelhttp.WithClientTrace(func(ctx context.Context) *httptrace.ClientTrace {
            return otelhttptrace.NewClientTrace(ctx)
        }), otelhttp.WithTracerProvider(provider), otelhttp.WithSpanNameFormatter(name),
    )
}

func name(_ string, req *http.Request) string {
    return "HTTP " + req.Method + " " + req.URL.Path
}

those screenshots for my issue:

when the http request fail (works): https://pasteboard.co/fPiiVRdBQ3xl.png

when the http request succeed (orphan spans): https://pasteboard.co/E760KguUUQd4.png


I expect to have no orphan spans
Thank you in advance!

Maybe that's a bug worth being reported in github? When I raised an issue there some time ago, they where rather responsive.
